# swift converting date from Gregorian to Islamic not showing correct date

Tags: swift, nsdate

I have this function for converting `Gregorian` date to `Islamic` date :

```
    func toIslamic() -> String {
    let dateFormatter: DateFormatter = DateFormatter()

    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en")
    let GregorianDate = dateFormatter.date(from: "23/03/1992")
    let islamic = Calendar(identifier: Calendar.Identifier.islamicUmmAlQura)
    let components = (islamic as NSCalendar?)?.components(NSCalendar.Unit(rawValue: UInt.max), from: GregorianDate!)
    let fina_date = "\(components!.day!)/\(components!.month!)/\(components!.year!)"
    print("final Islamic Date :: \(fina_date)") // 18/9/1412
    return fina_date

}
```

the output date is not correct as should be :

func output :

```
print("final Islamic Date :: \(fina_date)") // 18/9/1412
```

output should be :

```
20/9/1412
```

Is there something that I'm missed ?

Comment: Not related to the issue but in Swift 3+ you should get the date components directly `islamic.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: GregorianDate!)`, without casting to `NSCalendar`

Comment: Hi @vadian , I change `components` as your reply to  `islamic.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: GregorianDate!)` but still same result

Comment: I am not familiar with islamic calendars, but if with `Calendar(identifier: .islamicTabular)` instead of `.islamicUmmAlQura` I get the expected result `20/9/1412` – does that make any sense?

Comment: Hi @MartinR , if i convert today's Islamic date '09/06/1439' with option `.islamicTabular` result will be '24/2/2018' that mean today's Islamic date == yesterday Georgian date , also i tried other options such `.islamicCivil`, `.islamic` all of them but no luck with correct result with all cases :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no guarantee that you will have the correct data during this conversion , your app should provide a correction part that the user can select +1 , +2 ,-1 and -2 to the current displayed date that you should add to the date you get from conversions , and this is found even in most famous apps like [MuslimPro](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/muslim-pro-azan-quran-qibla/id388389451?mt=8)

Comment: thank you for your answer, yes I see correct duration days in most of iOS apps, but for php date convertor I didn't see it, and I don't know why. I believe should be a generic solution, because the converting is working fine on dates that not so far (ex: 2017, 2016)

Comment: you can try connecting to server that correctly displays the date  like famous islamic websites parse html and grab date